# What to do with interprocess communication between two processes?

Tags: c#, process, ipc, mutex

I need some help regarding interprocess communication.

I have an Application A and Application B.
Application B purpose is to update Application A. As Application A can't update himself, there must be some dll's need to be updated that is why Applicaiton B is used.
Appication A launches App B and App B closes App A and start updating A.
The updater process is two step
1) Copies the msi bits
2) Install the bits

If the user cancels Application B in first step while App A is waiting, is there any way to signal Application A go to ahead launching Application A as updating is been cancelled.

What is the best way to achieve this and how? Is a Mutex the only solution?

Comment: mutex are surely not the only solution. Do you have the full control on both applications and are those two Windows Forms or WPF applications? if B is canceled you want A to continue to do what? Open B again or ignore and continue working normally?

Comment: Both are WPF Applications.Yes I do have control. If B is cancelled I want A to continue normally

Comment: can you edit your question with more details? Like, can user keep using A while B is running? why do you need to have two separated applications?

Comment: @David:I have added more detailed description of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [XDMessaging](https://github.com/TheCodeKing/XDMessaging.Net), which uses Windows Messaging or File IO for IPC. You can also use a global [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) or [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to achieve basic signalling.

Alternatively a basic approach (if this fits). The following starts Application B in a new process and blocks until it's exited. You can use exit codes to control behaviour.

```
Process appB = Process.Start("C:\\applicationb.exe");
appB.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = appB.ExitCode;
```

You could also create an update MSI that runs in parallel with some custom dialog, and use a custom action to close the other app before updating. There's a number of ways to achieve this, from killing the process to signalling via Windows Messaging.

Comment: I dont want to use third party library :(

Comment: You could always use Process with WaitForExit to continue when the second app exits, is this what you want?

Comment: I think that's what I wanted.

Comment: I thought A starts B, and A continues to run. If B is canceled, B quits and A continues (not restarted). Otherwise A quits and B continues. WaitForExit in A will only work if B terminates A. But probably A wants to close itself in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `Mutex` for this. I'd use an `EventWaitHandle`. See [Send message from one running console app to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480430/send-message-from-one-running-console-app-to-another/480707#480707) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this should be done using IPC. I think `B` should start `A` if user cancels download.

That is,

1. `A` dies as soon as `B` starts.
2. `B` download and then applies the msi
3. `B` starts `A` and exits. This happens irrespective of whether download completes or not